# Are gaussian functions that have different kernel parameters orthogonal to each other?

Tags: normal-distribution, orthogonality

If we have n gaussians where they have different scale and location parameters -- are they orthogonal to each other?

By orthogonal I mean that the inner product is zero -- like it is for two cosine functions that have a different phase.

So, by Gaussian I mean the normal function used for it's properties as a function and not as a source of Random variables.

Comment: Orthogonal meaning uncorrelated?

Comment: Orthogonal meaning inner product is zero like say two cosine functions with different phase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not related at all. For example let $X_{i}$ be i.i.d Gaussian distributions of pdf
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}{e^{-x^2/2}}
$$
Then by definition we have $Cov(X_{i},X_{j})=0$ because $X_{i},X_{j}$ are independent. On the other hand if we have
$$
X\sim N(0,1), X_{1}\sim aX+b, a,b\not=0
$$
Then we have
$$
Cov(X,X_{1})=a^2\not=0
$$
Thus $X,X_{1}$ are correlated while $X_{1}\sim N(b,a)$.

Comment: That is what I thought too -- but how do people use Gaussians for Radial Basis Functions Basis?

Comment: @user1172468: Are you talking about support vector machines? The basis functions in that setting just means they need a function that decays radially. Gaussians usually represent "noise" in statistics.

Comment: yes to as for example in support vector machines and not as random variables

Comment: @user1172468: So I am afraid for SVM this is all I can help. I do not think it means "basis" in the usual mathematical setting. Rather it is a convenient way to express a multi-variate function as $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i}f_{i}$, with each $f_{i}$ being normal. I suspect the decomposition may not even be unique. In general I think you can get more help from the crossvalidated website.

Comment: Thanks -- that sounds right -- I think disciplines use concepts differently

Comment: Y'all know a basis doesn't have to be orthogonal, right?

Answer (score 3):

Heavens, no. Recall that for two functions $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, their inner product is $\langle f,g\rangle = \int fg\ dx$.  In fact, two positive functions whose supports intersect can never be orthogonal. This is because their product is positive, hence its integral is positive.

As Gaussians are supported on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and are positive, no two Gaussians can be orthogonal.

Comment: What if we have two Gaussians and we multiply one of them by -1?

Comment: @user1172468 Then their product will be everywhere negative. $\langle f,-g\rangle = -\langle f,g\rangle \neq 0$.